# javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects cannot be cast to org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl

Tags: jsp

## My Problem:

hi everybody I have get stuck in crazy to google seach for error 
" javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects cannot be cast to org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl."

### My Try

after i resolved it.if you get error above  let check lib 
"Example you have  lib available and after you continute download it form maven..."
problem is version of lib.

With me
I have **jsp-api.jar and jsp-api-2.1.jar** in library.@@
hope to help you.:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

in my case it's **standard.jar** and **jstl1.2.jar**.

hope this would help someone.